# Can't get DataNucleus JDO metadata only mapping to work

Tags: java, xml, maven, jdo, datanucleus

The DataNucleus JDO Mapping Guide states:

> So you can provide the metadata via annotations solely, or via
>   annotations plus ORM XML Metadata overrides, **or via JDO XML Metadata
>   solely**, or via JDO XML Metadata plus ORM XML Metadata overrides, or
>   finally via a Metadata API.

Emphasis mine.

I took the following class from the [JDO tutorial](http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jdo/tutorial.html#step1):

```
package org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial;

public class Product
{
    String name = null;
    String description = null;
    double price = 0.0;

    public Product(String name, String desc, double price)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = desc;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

And created the following `package.jdo`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jdo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/jdo/jdo"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/jdo/jdo http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/jdo/jdo_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
   <package name="org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial">
      <class name="Product" identity-type="datastore" table="product">
         <inheritance>
            <discriminator strategy="class-name"/>
         </inheritance>
         <datastore-identity>
            <column name="product_ID"/>
         </datastore-identity>
         <field name="name">
            <column name="name" jdbc-type="STRING" allows-null="true"/>
         </field>
         <field name="description">
            <column name="description" jdbc-type="STRING" allows-null="true"/>
         </field>
         <field name="price">
            <column name="price" jdbc-type="DOUBLE" allows-null="true"/>
         </field>
      </class>
   </package>
</jdo>
```

and put it in `src/main/resources/META-INF` ([as per documentation](http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jdo/metadata_xml.html)) in my maven project.

Now I'm unclear whether I need to perform the enhancing step with metadata only as well, but when I do I get the following output:

```
DataNucleus Enhancer completed with success for 0 classes. Timings : input=16 ms, enhance=0 ms, total=16 ms. Consult the log for full details

DataNucleus Enhancer completed and no classes were enhanced. Consult the log for full details
```

I wrote this test application:

```
package org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial;

import javax.jdo.JDOHelper;
import javax.jdo.Transaction;
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManager;
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PersistenceManagerFactory factory;
        factory = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("Tutorial");
        PersistenceManager manager = factory.getPersistenceManager();
        Transaction t = manager.currentTransaction();
        try {
            t.begin();
            Product obj = new Product("Test Product", "Test Product Description", 9.99);
            manager.makePersistent(obj);
            t.commit();
        } finally {
            if (t.isActive()) {
                t.rollback();
            }
            manager.close();
        }
    }
}
```

and get these errors when I run it with `mvn exec:java`:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:294)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.datanucleus.api.jdo.exceptions.ClassNotPersistenceCapableException: The class "org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial.Product" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException (NucleusJDOHelper.java:473)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent (JDOPersistenceManager.java:717)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent (JDOPersistenceManager.java:738)
    at org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial.Test.main (Test.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:294)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotPersistableException: The class "org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial.Product" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.assertClassPersistable (ExecutionContextImpl.java:5113)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectInternal (ExecutionContextImpl.java:1887)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectWork (ExecutionContextImpl.java:1830)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObject (ExecutionContextImpl.java:1685)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent (JDOPersistenceManager.java:712)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent (JDOPersistenceManager.java:738)
    at org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial.Test.main (Test.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:294)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Forgot to include my `persistence.xml` that I put in `src/main/resources/META-INF`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">

    <!-- JDO tutorial "unit" -->
    <persistence-unit name="Tutorial">
        <class>org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial.Inventory</class>
        <class>org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial.Product</class>
        <class>org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial.Book</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes/>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:postgresql://host/postgres"/>
            <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName" value="user"/>
            <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword" value="secret"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

I discovered in the [Persistence Guide](http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jdo/persistence.html#persistenceunit) that if you plan on using JDO Metadata only you need to specify a `package.jdo` file for your persistence unit using the `mapping-file` attribute instead of providing the actual class names.

Comment: because <class> is to define a class that has annotations (from the same guide). Also that only applies when you are using `persistence.xml` IIRC